# Flask - Apscheduler cannot call function that executes database command

Tags: python, flask, scheduler

```
Python: 2.7.3

Flask: 0.9
```

Hi, I want to make car simulator using `Apscheduler`. Each car has `distance` column in the database that will be incremented regularly.

Here's the import part

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
    abort, render_template, flash, views
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
from contextlib import closing
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
```

and here's the snippet of the code:

```
sched = Scheduler()
sched.add_interval_job(moveAllCars, seconds = 5)
sched.start()

def moveAllCars():
    print "debug 1"
    dbCommand = g.db.execute('SELECT CarID FROM Car')
    print "debug 2"
    #and so on
```

I did not write the full code because the error happened right after 'debug 1' with the error message: no handlers could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler". Google does not help much.

But the scheduler is still running, printing only 'debug1' every 5 seconds. The error message only come out during the first loop.

Anyone know the solution? Thanks before

[UPDATE]

After using `logging`, I found out it is RunTimeError: working outside of request context. Is there any other solution other than using with `app.test_request_context`?

Comment: related: [Python - No handlers could be found for logger “OpenGL.error”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345991/python-no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-opengl-error)

Comment: The logging says RunTimeError: working outside of request context. I think it is because I declared the `g.db` in other class. But I also have other class that use `g.db` without error. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g` is probably a `threading.local()`. Different threads see different values in it.

`g.db` is probably assigned a new db connection per request. No current request – no connection.

You could create db connection in move_all_cars() or pass it explicitly as a parameter.

Comment: I tried copying the `moveCar()` into the class that declare `g.db` but it still returns the same 'No handlers could be found for logger' error
I think I should handle the logger, but I cannot find good and simple solution in Google

Comment: to fix 'no handlers' configure logging. After that It will show what actual error you are having.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is as you said, it works on different thread. So I put the code that connect to database inside the moveCar()

Answer (score 3):

```
from os import getcwd
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
        filename=''.join([getcwd(), '/', 'log_file_name']),
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(levelname)s[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s'
)
```

Above did help in my case.

*KAcper*

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply, I already found the answer though. I will try your solution when I have chance