# I can not use the import command

Tags: linux, python-3.x, import

i can't import zxlolbot.py
have problem...

> No handlers could be found for logger "zxlolbot"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `zxlolbot` [uses `logging` module without configuring it properly](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library). You should see:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in `zxlolbot.py`. Add this line after it:

```
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

[To save logging messages to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file), you could add in `bot.py`:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='bot.log', level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: thanx, im testing... and feedback

Comment: @Buğraİşgüzar: it is incorrect. the last code snippet should go to your code `bot.py` (see my answer), not `zxlolbot.py`.

Comment: i install ubuntu 14 and fixed problem. TY

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you didn't set up the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) properly.

Comment: sorry because i have low english.

but i import and setup logger and import :/

Comment: You made a mistake in the setup. Comment out your setup and try with the basic setup from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345991/python-no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-opengl-error  
When this works, restore part of your custom setup until it breaks.

Comment: Recently I have not been resolved: / no logging module called a python3

Comment: Edit your question and show the code which you use and the error which you get.