# Custom logger error?

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to learn how to create a custom logger.  I'm not exactly sure what the below **error** is telling me, so if anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be great.

When I import and run the logger from my launcher.py file...

```
import custom_logging as logging
logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

**I get this error:**

```
No handlers could be found for logger "mb.custom-logger"
```

I know that the `custom-logger` part of the logger name is coming from within the `custom_logger/__init__.py` file....

```
... a bunch of code

log = getLogger('mb-logger')
log.warning('Creating log : {0}'.format(log_file))
```

But I'm not sure where the `mb` part comes from in the error message or what it relates to. Any thoughts?

Also to give some context, my project is set up like this:

```
Project_Root/
    bin/
        launcher.py (this is where the error is occurring)
    modules/
       custom-logger/
            source/
                custom_logger/
                    __init__.py (this is where the custom logger is created)
```

Comment: You probably need to show us how the custom logger is being created in the `__init__.py` script.

Comment: you may want to simplify the [project's directory structure](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#structure-of-the-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem.  @martineau suggested showing the code, so I started editing it to be more presentable.  During that process I found the error!

To answer my initial question, the `mb` in the error message refers to the root_logger.

When I was overriding the getLogger method inside of my custom_logger/**init**.py, the logger that I was returning didn't match up with the root logger. Like so:

**Error Code:**

```
root_logger = getLogger(mb_tool)                    # Name that needs to match = 'mb_tool'

def getLogger(name='default'):
    for handler in root_logger.handlers:
        handler.setLevel(DEBUG)
    return logging.getLogger(mb.{0}'.format(name))  # Name that doesn't match = 'mb'
```

**Fixed:**

```
root_logger = getLogger(mb_tool)  

def getLogger(name='default'):
    for handler in root_logger.handlers:
        handler.setLevel(DEBUG)
    return logging.getLogger(mb_tool.{0}'.format(name))
```

Changing the `mb` to `mb_tool` fixed everything.  Thanks for taking the time to help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Python - No handlers could be found for logger "OpenGL.error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345991/python-no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-opengl-error), to debug your code you need to have:

```
import custom_logging as logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

And then you should see the details of the error in the command line output.

My assumption is that you modified the logging module.

Comment: In my custom_logger/__init__.py I'm editing the logger config with a dictionary like in this example: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/logging/

    logging.config.dictConfig(log_settings);
    logging.captureWarnings(True);

Will calling basicConfig() override my custom settings?

Comment: Also, what does the 'mb' refer to in `mb.custom_logger`?